# How to prevent href from redirecting to exterior page.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Index.Html file that I want to open inside of a bootstrap modal without exiting the modal itself. Essentially acting as an internal link. I am trying to do this using ASP.net mvc. This location is being generated from Captivate 9, and I am attempting to add a single slide as a sample into the Modal

Javascript:

```
var modal3 = document.getElementById('myModal3');
var img3 = document.getElementById('myImg3');
var modalImg3 = document.getElementById("img03");
img3.onclick = function () {
    modal3.style.display = "block";

}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[2];
span.onclick = function () {
    modal3.style.display = "none";
}
```

Modal:

```
<div id="myModal3" class="modal">
    <span class="close" style="color:white">×</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I wrote that is similar to this is using Ajax. I am not sure you want to go this route, but it's worth a try at least! All you need to add is a btnCreate id on some element you are clicking and it should work!

```
    <!-- modal placeholder-->
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The html about is just the placeholder of your content you want to load.

This script simply opens the window and loads in the content. Almost intercepting it from your controller. This can be your PartialView you want to load into this Modal window!

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $("body").on("click", "#btnCreate", function (e) {
        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');
            bindForm(this);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

And then the closing of the modal window.

```
function bindForm(dialog) {
     $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                } else {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you. I appreciate your answer, and I will try this work around, I do not know that the ajax will be possible though, since this is being called from a partial.

Comment: As long as you are returning an ActionResult to the client the initial binding should grab that and insert it into the modal window. May require some playing around with.